# Styling label and hint in textComponent separately

Tags: codenameone

How can I style label and hint in text component separately?

```
TextComponent title = new TextComponent().labelAndHint("Title");
```

Comment: What's the use case for that? Notice you have two UIID's you can work with: `FloatingHint`, `TextComponent`